# what is the difference and which one better to use?

Tags: c#, generics, generic-list

What is the difference between the below 2 lines of code?

```
IList<Product> products = new List<Product>();

List<Product> products = new List<Product>();
```

I know I'm asking difference between `IList` & `List`, but what is the difference in above 2 lines of code?

Moreover, what are the advantages/disadvantages one over other? Is there any performance issue?

Simply what happens behind the scenes when using one over other? Thanks!

Comment: I can't wait till the day someone asks "what is the difference between X and Y?" without making **any** mention of performance whatsoever - not even through implication.

Comment: Nothing wrong with the question other than a duplicate. Close it, don't down vote it.

Comment: There is no difference of significance. One you are accessing through an interface, the other a concrete implementation. The duplicate has much more information on the topic :)